# Merging dataframe and simplefeature using R

Tags: r, merge

I'm working on converting an old script from using sp() to sf() and some of the computations have to be rewritten, including some operations which (used to) use `cbind` with `over()` like so:

```
cbind(df1data, over(df1 df2))
```

I've tried a number of combinations of `st_intersects`, `st_join`, and `merge_cols`, and can't seem to get the columns added on from the second `sf()`.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
# read in relevant polygons, Scottish Index of Multiple deprivation
if (file.exists("data/sc_dz_11.shp") == FALSE) {
download.file("http://simd.scot/2016/data/simd2016_withgeog.zip", 
              destfile = "data/simd2016_withgeog.zip")
unzip("data/simd2016_withgeog.zip", exdir = "data", junkpaths = TRUE)
}
simd_shapes <- st_read("data/sc_dz_11.shp")
simd_indicators <- read.csv("./data/simd2016_withinds.csv")
simd_indicators_min <- simd_indicators[c(1,6:17)]
# Original data is in wgs, so need to convert from wgs to bng to work with analysis across data sets
simd_wgs <- merge(x=simd_shapes, y=simd_indicators_min, by.x = "DataZone", by.y = "Data_Zone")
simd <- simd_wgs %>% st_transform(27700)

c1 <- c("site1","site2","site3")
c2 <- c("357109","350477.6", "257916")
c3 <- c("734754","614926.268", "662462")
df <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c3)

df_joined <- cbind(df@data, over(df, simd)) # of course this is the part where I'm struggling
df_joined <- bind_cols(df,st_intersects(df,simd)) # tried this too and it also didn't work
```

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `sp` and `sf` objects require an indication of which columns are X and Y, in this case that part was not done in the code, once you have a `sf` object, joins are natural. I did some polishing in the code, to make it reproducible:

```r
library(sf) 
library(dplyr)

dir.create("data") # so all dirs in IF statement work
if (file.exists("data/sc_dz_11.shp") == FALSE) {
  download.file("https://simd.scot/data/simd2016_withgeog.zip",   # URL had changed
                destfile = "data/simd2016_withgeog.zip")
  unzip("data/simd2016_withgeog.zip", exdir = "data", junkpaths = TRUE) 
}


simd_shapes <- st_read("data/sc_dz_11.shp")
simd_indicators <- read.csv("data/simd2016_withinds.csv")
simd_indicators_min <- simd_indicators[c(1,6:17)]

# let's also make this tidyverse 
simd_wgs = left_join(simd_shapes, simd_indicators_min, by = c("DataZone" = "Data_Zone"))

simd <- simd_wgs %>% st_transform(27700)

c1 <- c("site1","site2","site3")
c2 <- c("357109","350477.6", "257916")
c3 <- c("734754","614926.268", "662462")
df <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c3)

# convert to sf object
# |> is the R's pipe, for versions > 4
df = df |> st_as_sf(coords = c("c2", "c3")) |> st_set_crs(27700)

# now we join: 
df_joined = st_join(df, simd )

#Simple feature collection with 3 features and 23 fields
#Geometry type: POINT
#Dimension:     XY
#Bounding box:  xmin: 257916 ymin: 614926.3 xmax: 357109 ymax: 734754
#Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
#     c1       c3.1  DataZone                         Name TotPop2011 #ResPop2011 HHCnt2011 StdAreaHa StdAreaKm2 Shape_Leng Shape_Area
#1 site1     734754 S01007166         Carnoustie East - 04        709        #707       328  20.25832   0.202583   2620.603   202583.2
#2 site2 614926.268 S01012366 Hawick Central - Town Centre        864        #862       513  16.88552   0.168856   2706.169   168855.2
#3 site3     662462 S01009909             Strathbungo - 05        849        #821       471  21.71528   0.217151   4074.232   217152.8
```